# What's the relationship between cso files and dxil?

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl

The resulting compiled shader uses the default extension of `.cso` (Compiled Shader Object).

DXIL is intended to support a direct mapping of the HLSL programming language into Low-Level Virtual Machine Intermediate Representation (LLVM IR), suitable for consumption in GPU drivers.

Find some docs, but not very clearly.

Answer (score 2):

`CSO` is just a Visual Studio convention for the output binary of the HLSL compiler. It can be legacy FXC or modern DXC.

- It may contain "DirectX Byte Code" (DXBC) if it was generated by the legacy compiler.
- It may contain "DirectX Intermedia Language" (DXIL) if it was generated by the DXC compiler.
- For Xbox development, it may contain the precompiled IHV-specific microcode as well.

There's no metadata associated with a `CSO` so you have to know what it's supposed to be used for. The only convention here is that it's the binary blob you pass to the DirectX API to create a shader object at runtime.